# Type an interface property to allow for multiple independent types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I want an external type (from react-hook-form) in a React component to allow for 3 specific types. They represent an object with formvalues.

I was expecting that it could be done with an union type, but this will complain when passing down `TypeA` on an instance, that it is missing properties from the other types.

```
interface ComponentProps {
   setValue: UseFormSetValue<TypeA | TypeB | TypeC> 
}
```

Whats the best way of allowing for type a, b or c, without merging it all into 1 big interface where all the properties are optional?

I have learned that a union type such as `type Fruit = TomatoType | GrapeType | BananaType` does get treated as what I am looking for. Why does this not work the same way?

Is it related to the external type UseFormSetValue? This is how it appears to be typed:

```
type UseFormSetValue<TFieldValues extends FieldValues> = <TFieldName extends Path<TFieldValues> = Path<TFieldValues>>(name: TFieldName, value: PathValue<TFieldValues, TFieldName>, options?: Partial<...> | undefined) => void
```

This is how I pass it in the component instance itself.

```
const { setValue } = useForm({ defaultValues: ...object as TypeA });

<Component setValue={ setValue } />
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add some test cases, currently this questions lacks details

Comment: @wonderflame i thought it was a generic question. I'll add some more details to help explain what my confusion is.

Comment: Can you include the code where you actually pass the props to the component?

Comment: So I just did a test with a union of just the object types. This seems to work like I expected. So it is probably related to the `UseFormSetValue` type that is imported from react-hook-form library. I have included a screenshot of how that type is constructed. Hopefully that helps. I will also add some code of how I pass it down to the component.

Comment: Please avoid images, include the code itself

Comment: @wonderflame no problem, i have changed to text

Comment: What is `client`, `ClienType`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254196/discussion-between-sarogfx-and-wonderflame).

Comment: @wonderflame, mistake from copy (edited), it is supposed to one of the objects (typeA, typeB). So basically the union i am trying to add, are specific forms that this component is used on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic react component. Here is how you can restrict the number of types:

```
interface UseFormSetValue<T> {
  name?: "John";
  age: T;
}

interface ComponentProps<T> {
  value: UseFormSetValue<T>;
}

function TestComp<T extends number | string>({ value }: ComponentProps<T>) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{`You are ${value.age} years old`}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TestComp;
```

Then you can pass your value types:

```
    <div className="App">
      <TestComp<string> value={{ age: "21" }} />
      <TestComp<number> value={{ age: 32 }} />
      <TestComp<string> value={{ age: "Twelve" }} />
    </div>
```

Notice that you can't pass another type now, like:

```
<TestComp<boolean> value={{ age: true }} />
```

Here is a [link for sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/generic-component-329spp?file=/src/App.tsx:183-223)

Comment: Thank you but the UseFormSetValue is an imported type from react-form-hook, so i cannot create my own interface.

Comment: I know, I just have put it there to demonstrate how it's done. You can place your constraints ie. `TypeA | TypeB` in `<T extends number | string>` place. notice how the generic for ComponentProps is received with <T>. But there is no need to use union types inside UseFormSetValue generic.

Comment: When I try this, I get an error 'cannot find name T'. I am worries I might have the syntax wrong. Could you show me your example but with a `const Component:FC<> = ({}) => {} notation`? This is what I have tried: `const Component: FC<T extends TypeA | TypeB> = ({ setValue }: ComponentProps<T> ) => {}` and for the interface i have `interface ComponentProps<T> {
    setValue: UseFormSetValue<T>;
  
}`